# How can I read an LP/MPS file in pulp?

Tags: python, pulp, mps

I have a LP/MPS file like this:

```
Maximize
3x + 2y

Subject To
Constraint1: x + 2y <= 5
Constraint2: 2x - y >= 3

Bounds
0 <= x <= 10
y >= 0

General
x, y

End
```

Can I read it in pulp or I have to read by myself?
I've tried to read it by myself, and it's very complicated. I also searched on the internet for how to read an LP/MPS file, but I didn't find any instructions.
Thanks

Comment: You'll have to rewrite the problem in python. See [pulp examples](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/tree/master/examples). MPS is an __old__ format (punch card old), you probably don't want to go there.

Comment: I don't get what you mean, I want to read that file to pulp and solve it, your example is write the problem into a file, right?

Comment: You cannot read your file in. You must rewrite the problem in the form shown in the pulp examples.

Comment: oh, after rewrite can I read that file?